# Formating number in folder name

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting

I have a program which iterates and creates folders whose names contains variables (e.g, "Folder 3, iteration 27").
Those folders are created with the *os* package.

```
os.makedirs(pathFolder+ '/Factor %f' %factor + ' and Tmin %i' %Tmin)
```

The factor variable is a float type with value 0.7, and the folder, when it's been created has the following name:

```
Factor 0.70000 and Tmin 2
```

I want to get only 0.7 in the folder's name, not the following zeros.

I have tried the *round* function, but the same problem appears.

Any ideas?

Comment: @zondo that solved my problem! Thanks!

Comment: @alfasin  that also solved my problem! Thanks!